# Using My namespace in a module

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I tried to use MY namespace in a module in VB.NET , but it says "My isn't declared ..." Using MY namespace would save a lot of time , but can I use it in a module ?

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module Entry_Module
    Sub Main()
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run\", "MyApp", application.executeablepath, RegistryValueKind.String)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I'm adding my application to startup , the application i have has no Form but modules instead . So How can I use my namespace in this module ?

Comment: I can use `My` namespace in any module or class of my project, even in the Console projects. Are you sure you are using it inside a method, property, etc?

Comment: Can you make a small code sample that won't compile and add that to your question?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can use `My` in a module. Your code works for me. It has to be anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `My` namespace inside a Method in order to be available, I think that is your problem. See:

```
Public Class MyClass
    My.<Does not work>

    Public Sub MyMethod()
        My.<Correct>
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyway, if you want to use it anywhere you can create a new class in order to retrieve the information you want:

```
Public Class MyNS
    Public Shared Function CurrentDirectory() As String
        Return My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory()
    End Function

    'etc
End Class
```

And then use it everywhere calling the class method: `MyNS.CurrentDirectory()`

**Extra information**:
[`My` namespace and project types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172698.aspx).

Comment: @user1970090 Please share an example of your code that didn't work. Edit your question and add the extra information.